# ajax call - ?"" is added to url

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I am trying to make an ajax call against the server, and can't get through, as ?"" is always appended to my url.

Here's my call:

```
let method = 'GET';
let url = 'http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar';
var username = username;
var password = password;

$.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: url,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  error: function(Response) {
    console.log(Response);
  },
  success: function(Response) {
    console.log(Response);
  }
});
```

When watching the call in firefox network console, the url shows as:

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar?""
```

And i get a 400 response.
So, why is ?"" added to the url?

Comment: This behaviour is may be because of sending *get* request. But that should not matter.

Comment: Are you sure it's not more something like `?_=1511292839`? Have you looked at the actual content of the response? I don't think that the addition of that part after the `?` is likely to cause a 400 response.

Comment: No, it does not add a timestamp cache number...
Just ?""

Our API triggers 400 response, because it is waiting for keys after the ?

Comment: @toni_latenz, will you please create plunkr or jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I am sorry, i tried, but can't get a jsfiddle to work for this particular problem.

Comment: Are you the maintainer of the API? If so, I would advise you to fix it so that it doesn't break when a `?` is present. That's not normal.